# Ionic debug option missing, gives error "spawn adb ENOENT"

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, react-tsx

I'm developing a React (v18.2.0) typescript (v4.1.3) application with Ionic (CLI v5.4.16) and Capacitor (CLI v5.4.1) in VS Code (v1.85.2) on Windows 11.

Normally, to debug (set breakpoints, step through, etc), I click the Ionic extension (v1.66.0) in VS Code, it asks me to sign up or log in, I click skip for now, then I go under the Debug category, click "Chrome", and it opens a Chrome (v120.0.6099.225) window. However, now when I try to go under the Debug category, an error pops up in the bottom right that says:

```
spawn adb ENOENT
```

I have tried multiple other solutions found for similar errors, but none of them fixed this problem. This is probably because the other problems I found occurred when simply starting the app (not debugging), or the problems had a slightly different error.

I tried to debug it on my Mac as well, but the same exact error occurred. This has never occurred previously on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

For my windows machine I fixed it by adding `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` to environment path. This folder is where the `adb` cli tool resides. Restarted VS code and voila it worked.

This error accurs when the debugger cannot find the proper tool to debug. In my case when I added an android project in my solution the extension started throwing this error.

If you have and android project you need the cli tool `adb` (Android Debug Bridge) to be available. It comes with android studio. Try it in your terminal if you can run adb. In my case it was not recognized.

This solution was solved with the help from this [Vs code extension issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/vscode-extension/issues/146) which explains it even better.